# libxml/tree.h no such file or directory after integrating three20 library

Tags: objective-c, three20, touchxml

i am getting Libxml/tree.h:No such file or directory error and other xml related error after adding three20 library to my project.

i have added -lxml2 to other linker flags 
i have added /usr/include/libxml2 to header search path.

but still getting error

previously when i used old version of three20 there was no error but after adding new three20 the errors pops up

help is appreciated
thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

finally i found the answer and fixed my problem

previously i ve added three20 using pythone script to my project as suggested by three20 in terminal window.
so now i manually added three20 myself as described below in this link
https://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/master/README.mdown

and voila got rid of errors

Comment: That works, I also had to remove the -ObjC and -all_load flags.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I read somewhere that using a pythone script they use something like -forceload which then somehow force Xcode to overlook otherLikerFlag thing.

So I think that why to manually add the three20 to the project, the otherLinkerFlag will still be called. Hence, /usr/include/libxml2 would work.

Just to confirm, i add thee20 the manual way it works now. It might take a while but so far I found that it is the most stable way to work with three20